# Sonar compatibility with windows opereting systems

Tags: sonarqube

I want to ask is sonar compatible with all versions of windows operating systems? If i will install and run sonar on windows 8 or windows server 2012 or on any other windows OS then will it work fine??

Kindly revert in case anyone have any idea on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, except Windows Mobile :)
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements